# yahoo YQL to find industry that a ticker belongs to

Tags: yahoofinance

YQL has different companies that are listed under an industry:

e.g. select * from yahoo.finance.industry where id="112"

Is there a way to query the table for a ticker symbol and find out to which industry the company belongs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the package pandas_finance does the job :-)

```
from pandas_finance import Equity
aapl = Equity('AAPL')
aapl.industry
```

Comment: Could you be so kind to tell us how with an example?